# Bug: angular.js edit form sends two put requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't reproduce this bug or figure out the cause of it: A user edits a form and submits, the changes are saved via PUT request, there is a GET request for data reload, but sometimes there is a second PUT request reverting the changes to the original values.
I've checked the logs and this second PUT request happens within seconds of the first PUT request. I have yet to reproduce this and the user says they did not edit a second time.

In the edit controller:

```
  $scope.save = function() {
    $scope.requestPending = true;
    APIResources.userResource($route.current.userType,$route.current.params.id).update(makeUpdateObject()).$promise.then(function(data) {
        $scope.userRefresh();
        $scope.requestPending = false;
        $rootScope.$broadcast('app.event.user.updated');
    },
    function(error){
      console.log('Error saving', error);
    });
    $scope.$dismiss();
  };
```

In the user controller:

```
  $scope.userRefresh = function() {
    APIResources.userResource($route.current.userType,$route.current.params.id).get().$promise.then(function(data) {
      $scope.user = data;
      // Time to reload the data is 2000ms to support 2G (450kbs) or higher 
      window.setTimeout(function() {
        $rootScope.$broadcast('app.user.loaded', data, userType);
      }, 2000);
    }, function(err) {
      console.log('Data failed to load.');
    });
  };
```

Comment: It's pretty hard debugging something you cannot reproduce. And what a user says they have done is not always very reliable.

Comment: it's always good to disable the button for the user for saving until the server is done and the success is recieved

Comment: Yes, the button is disabled until success. I'm going on a hunch the user just forgot they updated twice.